# Is writing helper functions for state passing style idiomatic in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, idioms

I'm working on some code for a card game:

```
splitCards_ (x:xs) (a,b,c) | isGold x   = splitCards xs (a:x,b,c) 
                           | isAction x = splitCards xs (a,b:x,c)
                           | isVP x     = splitCards xs (a,b,c:x)
splitCards_ [] (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)

splitCards xs = splitCards_ xs ([],[],[])
```

Essentially, taking a list of cards, and splitting it into three different lists depending on the type of the card. `splitCards_` represents state updates by recursively updating it's parameters, then `splitCards` (the actual function) is used to always start the computation with the three lists of specific types of cards empty.

I believe this is called state-passing style, and I'm pretty sure that's perfectly idiomatic, but I'm more concerned with the fact that I have to define a helper function `splitCards_` in order to get this to work the way I want. Is creating helper functions like this idiomatic Haskell? Is there a cleaner way to write this? Are there naming conventions preferable to just putting an underscore on the end of the name of the helper function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly idiomatic style. It's a classic way to make a function tail recursive. (Although that's less important and slightly more nuanced in Haskell).

Moreover, making helper functions is definitely good and a key part of *many* common patterns. If you feel that something is more natural factored out, go for it! Unless it's taken to an extreme, it helps readability.

The main suggestion I have is putting the helper function into a `where` clause. This way, it will only be visible in the scope of the main function which makes it clear that it's just a helper. The name you give the helper function is less important; `splitCards_` is fine, but `splitCards'` (pronounced "splitCards prime") and `go` (a generic name for helper functions) would be more common. So I would rewrite your code something like this:

```
splitCards xs = go xs ([],[],[]) 
  where go (x:xs) (a, b, c) | isGold x   = go xs (a:x,b,c) 
                            | isAction x = go xs (a,b:x,c)
                            | isVP x     = go xs (a,b,c:x)
        go [] (a, b, c) = (a, b, c)
```

Note that these are just cosmetic changes—what you were doing is *fundamentally* sound.

The two naming options (`go` vs `splitCards'`) is just a matter of preference.

I personally like `go` because, once you're used to the convention, it clearly signals that something is just a helper function. In a sense,  `go` is almost more like syntax than a function of its own; it's meaning is purely subordinate to the `splitCards` function.

Others do not like `go` because it is a little cryptic and somewhat arbitrary. It might also make the recursive structure of your code less clear because you're recursing on `go` and not the function itself.

Go for whatever you think looks best.

Answer (score 3):

I have nothing much to add to @Tikhon's answer except that in this specific case you could use the `partition` function from `Data.List`:

```
splitCards xs = 
  let (as,bs) = partition isGold xs
      (cs,ds) = partition isAction bs
  in (as,cs,ds) -- (golds, actions, others)
```

Due to lazy evaluation it should have essentially the same performance as your hand-crafted version.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, code as yours is idiomatic, especially if cleaned up a bit as @Tikhon suggested. In the specific case, your recursion scheme appears to be a left fold, so it is usually made that explicit in the code. Building upon @Tikhon's code:

```
splitCards xs = foldl' separate ([],[],[]) xs
  where separate (a, b, c) x | isGold x   = (a:x,b,c) 
                             | isAction x = (a,b:x,c)
                             | isVP x     = (a,b,c:x)
```

The first line can even be eta-contracted (not much needed in this case, IMHO, but ...)

```
splitCards = foldl' separate ([],[],[])
  where ...
```